# Bulk AWS Lambda Upload from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Using the AWS tool plugin for Visual Studio, how do you do a bulk upload of Lambda functions to AWS?

I have a project that contains two functions that define separate lambda functions. The context menu for AWS Lambda seems to only allow for publishing one function at a time. As you can imagine, that is a bit of a maintainability nightmare.

The json config file that it generates does not have any answers either as it seems to be pretty flat and only allows a single function at a time:

```
"region"      : "us-west-2",
"configuration" : "Release",
"framework"     : "netcoreapp1.0",
"function-runtime" : "dotnetcore1.0",
"function-memory-size" : 256,
"function-timeout"     : 5,
"function-handler"     : "LambdaSamples::LambdaSamples.SampleFunction::HelloWorld",
"function-name"        : "HelloWorld",
"function-role"        : "lambda_basic_execution",
"environment-variables" : ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio project called "AWS Lambda Project" is designed for single Lambda functions.

So if your solution has multiple projects, and you want to deploy them all at once, you're best off doing it by script/command line.

The `Readme.md` file generated by the new project wizard has instructions on deploying by command line using `dotnet lambda deploy-function`.

Comment: Do you know of any sample scripts that do this sort of thing? Or should I just hack one together myself?

Comment: Offhand, I don't know any. But a simple batch file or Powershell script should suffice.

Comment: I was really just misunderstanding the architecture of a serverless app. I assumed I would need a lambda function for each endpoint in my api. Turns out the entire project is hosted in a single lambda function. It wasn't clear to me from the documentation I was looking at.

Answer (score 0):

I generally create an options file for each type of release that I want, like this (the new file is aws-options-live.json and has a specific name / env variables pertaining to my live environment):

[image: aws options]

And then use the following in a batch file in a Deploy folder off of the main solution folder:

```
echo off
cd ..\ApiGatewayLambda
dotnet lambda deploy-function -cfg aws-options-live.json
set /p asd="Hit enter to continue"
```

You can then get as clever as you want to with linking multiple uploads together / error checking etc.

You can still right click on the project and choose Public to AWS Lambda - it will use the aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json file to publish the function.